# Is it possible to automatically end old instances when I launch/debug my application?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

When I run/debug my application, I would like any old instances of my application to be closed automatically, rather than getting two separate instances running.

I'm specifically concerned with Jython programs, which I'm using the Pydev, an Eclipse extension, to write. However, I'm not sure if this would be a PyDev or an Eclipse setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's just for PyDev, there's an option to restart the last launch: Ctrl+Shift+F9 while focusing the PyDev editor -- if you have the console open, there's a relaunch button -- right next to the terminate all ;)